# XMl newbie - How can I return specific elements from another XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

From a weather feed I'm getting this element in an XSLT fragment:

```
<xsl:value-of select="data/current_condition/weatherCode"/>
```

This returns a number e.g. 122

I have another XML which lists the weather code details e.g.:

```
<condition>
<code>122</code>
<description>Overcast</description>
<day_icon>wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud</day_icon>
<night_icon>wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud</night_icon>
</condition>
<condition>
<code>119</code>
<description>Cloudy</description>
<day_icon>wsymbol_0003_white_cloud</day_icon>
<night_icon>wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud</night_icon>
</condition>
```

So how do I dynamically get e.g. code 122's description, icon etc ?

Comment: So you want a single XSLT stylesheet to work with two XML documents, is that right? It would be useful to have some more of the first XML document and your XSLT to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="weather_desc" select="document('2.xml')/root"/>

<xsl:variable name="weather_code" select="data/current_condition/weatherCode"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$weather_desc/condition[code=$weather_code]/description"/>
```

Comment: Borodin - yes I wanted a single XSLT stylesheet to work with two XML documents. Panda-34 - Thank you so very much - Brilliant answer (I had to delete '/root' but otherwise a perfect response). Very much appreciated.